# [Python - scipy]: Genarate random samples from custom multivariate Probability Density Function (PDF)

Tags: python, random, scipy, probability-distribution

I want to **generate** random **sample (vector X)**:

```
X = [x1, x2, x3, ..., x_d]
```

where **X follows** a **custom** multivariate **Probability Density Function**.

I am using **Python - scipy** and I overvide the PDF function to follow a combination of multivariate normal distributions.

For example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats._multivariate import multivariate_normal_gen, multivariate_normal, _squeeze_output


class multivar_rv(multivariate_normal_gen):

    def pdf(self, x, mean=None, cov=1, allow_singular=True):
        mean = [
            [0, 1],
            [2, 5]
        ]
        cov = [
            [
                [1, 0],
                [0, 1]
            ],
            [
                [1.5, 0],
                [0, 1.5]
            ]
        ]
        weight = [.5, .5]
        return sum(weight[i] * multivariate_normal(mean[i], cov[i]).pdf(x) for i in range(len(mean)))
```

The following image shows the plot of the above code.
[image]

Now I want to **generate samples given the above distribution**, however if I use *rvs()* (from scipy.stats._multivariate.multivariate_normal_gen) the function is not overrided and the results will be generated from the default normal distribution:

```
P.rvs()
```

What do I have to do in order to change this and override this function so that the generated samples follow my PDF?

Thank you!

Comment: does this help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70855/generating-random-variables-from-a-mixture-of-normal-distributions

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106806/how-to-do-a-simple-gaussian-mixture-sampling-and-pdf-plotting-with-numpy-scipy

Comment: dear @piterbarg thank you for your comment in fact it helped generate some samples and the error from the actual PDF was not that big, so I used that

Answer (score 0):

That is because the the rvs method that your class inherits (i.e. that of multivariate_normal_gen) uses an instance of multivariate_normal_gen directly that is declared outside of the class definition ([see lines 657 and 682 in the source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2e5883ef7af4f5ed4a5b80a1759a45e43163bf3f/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py#L633-L682)) to generate samples. You have to write your own rvs method explicitly.